# Uniqe arrays contains two values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, unique, dynamic-arrays

I have row:

[image]

I want to add this value to tab/arrays, to get pairs as below:

[0] = Eng, 3

[ 1] = PL, 4

[2] = US, 5
...

[x] = value, col_number

**Please tell me how to**:

1) add second value

2) check if arrays contains "Eng" or "PL"

*So far I have*:

```
Dim CatTab() As Variant
Dim tabSize as Long
For b = 3 To 20
    Category = wsSum.Cells(2, b).Value
    tabSize = tabSize + 1
    ReDim Preserve CatTab(tabSize)
    CatTab(tabSize) = Category
Next
```

Comment: You can declare an array of 2 dimensions, e.g. `Dim CatTab(4,4)`. Don't think you need Redim as you seem to know the size upfront.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using a two dimensional array instead for storing seperate values.

```
Dim CatTab As Variant
'First dimension can't be redimmed, use this for headers. Second dimension can, use this to extend data.
ReDim CatTab(1 To 2, 1 To 1)

Dim tabSize As Long
For b = 3 To 20
    'Check if a resize is required
    If CatTab(1, UBound(CatTab, 2)) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve CatTab(1 To UBound(CatTab, 1), 1 To UBound(CatTab, 2) + 1)
    'Add value
    CatTab(1, UBound(CatTab, 2)) = wssum.Cells(2, b)
    'Add column
    CatTab(2, UBound(CatTab, 2)) = b
Next
```

To iterate through to check for a specific value..

```
Dim lng As Long
For lng = LBound(CatTab, 2) To UBound(CatTab, 2)
    If InStr(1, CatTab(1, lng), "Eng") <> 0 Or InStr(1, CatTab(1, lng), "PL") <> 0 Then
        'code here
    End If
Next lng
```